# How to shift the most inner rectangle inside the most outer rectangle

Tags: javascript, css, math, canvas, geometry

I'm working on centering the most inner (the **red** shape) on *X-axis* to the center of the most outer shape (the **black** shape), while the **red** shape keeps its coordinates/position inside its direct parent, i.e. the **blue** shape.

For example, centering the **red** shape from this original image (dimensions are shown on the second picture):

[image: Original picture]

should look like that:

[image: Centered red shape]

Additionally, the **blue** shape can be anywhere inside **black** shape, and **red** anywhere inside **blue**.

It's basic math :) and I'm having troubles with coming up with a general **math** formula on how to center the **red** shape inside the **dark** one while maintaining its position inside the **blue** shape. Could somebody direct or explain me how to do this?

**NOTE** the values (widths) are in pixels and are not accurate.

Comment: Once red is centered on black and blue moves +10px, then counter-move red -10px and red is centered again. However, your question is, how to get red centered in black with arbitrary positioning of blue in the first place.  Is that correct?  Regards, M.

Comment: @Micha, the red shape keeps its position inside the blue shape, I mean the blue shape also can shift to the left or right inside black shape (can go out of bounds too) with the red shape inside it in the same position but centered in the very center of the black shape

Answer (score 1):

Just store the distance between the red box and its parent, center the red box and then change the parent by using the stored distance:

```
let distance = red.x - redParent.x;                       // storing the distances between the red box and its parent

red.x = black.x + black.width / 2 - red.width / 2;        // centering the red box horizontally according to the black box

redParent.x = red.x - distance;                           // changing the red box parent position accordingly
```